# Routing multiple params / paths to single method

Tags: 8, routes

I'm attempting to create the following routing :

```
/app/{type}
/app/{type}.{format}
/app/{type}/{limit}
/app/{type}/{limit}.{format}
```

I would like all of these routes to route to a single method. Do I need to declare a route for each of the paths and params ? Does the ranking of the routes also matter ? e.g do I have to place

> /app/{type}.{format}

first before

> /app/{type}

?

Comment: You can try [Dynamic routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122201) too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to define a route for each path.

The order should not matter, it will put them all in the router table and then "order" them by the best match first.